# Error in compiling, <identifier> expected.. Would love to know why is this happening and how I can fix it in the future

Tags: android

```
package edetect.webiscr.cf.e_bookgeneral;

import android.app.ActivityManager;

public class ApplockHandler {
    String appg = "com.example.lock";
    ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String appg);
}
```

The error results to  expected

```
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String appg);
```

I'm pretty new to java and android.. So sorry for my noobishness

Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `killBackgroundProcess` into a function, and only pass in `appg` without the `String` datatype in front of it. For example:

```
package edetect.webiscr.cf.e_bookgeneral;

import android.app.ActivityManager;

public class ApplockHandler {
    private final String appg = "com.example.lock";

    public ApplockHandler() {}

    public void killLock() {
        ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(appg);
    }
}
```

Comment: The coding you did made it into a static context which AM doesn't allow sadly

Comment: Yeah sorry wasn't thinking properly at the time. Sanjeet's answer would be correct in this case, my answer would be identical once I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Call **killBackgroundProcesses** from any function. Also you need to get an instance of **ActivityManager**.

```
public class ApplockHandler {

public ApplockHandler() {}

public void killLock(String appg) {
     ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);    

    am.killBackgroundProcesses(appg);
}
}
```

Now call this **killLock** method from anywhere by passing the package name.

Comment: Cannot find the symbol "Context"

Comment: You would need to add `Context` as an argument to `killLock()` and pass it in from your Activity/Service